# Raedric’s Hold sewer entrance

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

So Kolsc has told me there is a sewer entrance to the hold but I cannot find it anywhere.  I have found the vines and the guards outside the keep but cannot for the life of me find a sewer grate.  Has anyone got any guidance as to how to get in to the dungeon under Raedric’s Hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go around the right edge of the map, nearly until the end of the map. There are some stones in the water you can walk on, they lead directly to the sewer entrance.

[image]

[image]

There is also another entrance to the castle you can use:

> If you go around the left side of the map, there are some vines on the wall you can climb up.

Comment: Ha had literally just found the stones I could walk on across the water!  Thanks